# Sql injections, dvwa. Ошибка

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Привет всем, прохожу курс по Этичному хикингу, возник вопрос по поводу **Sql injections**, курс 2015 года, поэтому есть различие.

Первым делом я установил **apache2** и **Dvwa**, все прошло успешно.

Но потом возникла проблема в установке mysql-server, долго не мог решить вопрос, но потом мне подсказали, что есть проблема в установке, поэтому я установил mariaDB, аргументируя тем, что это новая ветвь в mysql.

Возникает ошибка в **localhost/dvwa/setup/php** [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Глянул **config.inc.php** ничего необычного
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сервисы apache2 и mysql работают исправно

```
# service apache2 status
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; disabled; vendor preset:
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2017-12-21 17:11:33 EST; 40min ago
  Process: 3194 ExecStop=/usr/sbin/apachectl stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS
  Process: 3199 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCE
 Main PID: 3203 (apache2)
    Tasks: 8 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/apache2.service
           ├─3203 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─3204 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─3205 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─3206 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─3207 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─3208 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─3209 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           └─3565 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start

дек 21 17:11:33 kali systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
дек 21 17:11:33 kali apachectl[3199]: AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably deter
дек 21 17:11:33 kali systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP Server.

# service mysql status
● mysql.service - LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/mysql; generated; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2017-12-21 17:45:22 EST; 6min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 5199 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/mysql stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 5232 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/mysql start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS
    Tasks: 29 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
           ├─5258 /bin/bash /usr/bin/mysqld_safe
           ├─5402 /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plu
           └─5403 logger -t mysqld -p daemon error

дек 21 17:45:22 kali mysqld[5403]: Version: '10.1.29-MariaDB-6'  socket: '/var/r
дек 21 17:45:22 kali mysql[5232]: Starting MariaDB database server: mysqld.
дек 21 17:45:22 kali systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start and stop the mysql database 
дек 21 17:45:22 kali /etc/mysql/debian-start[5453]: Upgrading MySQL tables if ne
дек 21 17:45:22 kali /etc/mysql/debian-start[5456]: /usr/bin/mysql_upgrade: the 
дек 21 17:45:22 kali /etc/mysql/debian-start[5456]: Looking for 'mysql' as: /usr
дек 21 17:45:22 kali /etc/mysql/debian-start[5456]: Looking for 'mysqlcheck' as:
дек 21 17:45:22 kali /etc/mysql/debian-start[5456]: This installation of MySQL i
дек 21 17:45:22 kali /etc/mysql/debian-start[5463]: Checking for insecure root a
дек 21 17:45:22 kali /etc/mysql/debian-start[5467]: Triggering myisam-recover fo
```

Лично мое мнение что не работает из за **mariadb**, но не знаю, что делать

Comment: Написано же, используй нормального юзера, а  не root'а...

Comment: @Fat-Zer это я понял, ток как использовать не root, поменять только в config.int? и выйти из под root пользователя

Comment: во-первых, root mysql'я и системный root — две разные сущности. во-вторых, да, просто создай нового пользователя в мускуле и заполни правильно конфиг.

Comment: Я сделал, проблема оказалась достаточно простой
используйте такие команды: 
`mysql -u root`
`use mysql;`
`update user set plugin='' where User='root';`
`flush privileges;`
`exit;`

Comment: для тестовой системы всё равно, но на реальной рабочей системе такое делать не стоит... по крайней мере если не понимаешь что именно и зачем сделал...

Comment: @Fat-Zer у меня virtualbox, спасибо за советы

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o7RxE_BzV4M Вот тут хорошо разобрано как все ставить, может быть кому то пригодиться